# Create a selected link to tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, selected

I'm trying to create a selected link to tabs that load content without reloading the page. I've tried so many things but I can't find one that works since I'm not using actual links `<a>` I just want them to change the state when selected.
Here's my code:
HTML

```
<nav class="secondMenu">
<label for="toggleMenu" class="menuTitle" onclick="">Categories</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggleMenu" />
<ul class="nav">
<li><div id="common" class="linkselected" >Common</div></li>
<li><div id="deposits" class="tab_button">Deposits</div></li>
<li><div id="withdrawals" class="tab_button">Withdrawals</div></li>
<li><div id="verification" class="tab_button">Verification</div></li>
<li><div id="account" class="tab_button">Account</div></li>
<li><div id="betting" class="tab_button">Betting</div></li>
<li><div id="bonus" class="tab_button">Bonus</div></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    bInfo: false,
    bFilter: false,
    bSort:false,
    bPaginate:false
  }); 

  $('.tab_button').on('click',function(){
      $('tbody tr').hide();
      $('tbody tr[type="'+this.id+'"].title').show();
    if(this.id == "comunes"){
        $('tbody tr').not('.title').show();
    }else{
      $('tbody tr[type="'+this.id+'"]:not(".title")').show();
    }
  });

    $('.secondMenu ul li').click(function(){
        console.log('hiding');
        $('.menuTitle').click();
        var title=$(this).find('.tab_button').html();
        console.log(title);
        $('.menuTitle').html(title);


    });


} );// JavaScript Document
```

hope I explained myself, thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "change the state when selected"?

Comment: just change the color and add a border bottom to the div or li item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i'm making the assumption that the selected list item should have the 'linkselected' class, which will style it accordingly.

```
$('.secondMenu ul li:not(.linkselected)').click(function(){
  $('.secondMenu ul li').removeClass('linkselected'); // remove the linkselected class whereever it may be
  $(this).addClass('linkselected'); // add it to the item that was just clicked on
});
```

You should also use the `'tab_button'` class on all items, including the currently selected `'linkselected'`, so update your html and include it on the first item.

Comment: Hi Pete, I managed to make it work by using this code:

 `$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.secondMenu ul li').click(function () {
            $('.secondMenu ul li').removeClass('linkselected');
            $(this).addClass('linkselected');
        });
    });`
and by adding 
a <li class> to the list item named 'linkselected'
thank you so much for taking your time to make a reply :)